# Trigonometric proof using identity?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

Using the formula for $\sin(A+B)$ and $\cos(A+B)$ show that:
$$\frac{\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)}{\sin(A-B)-\sin(A+B)} = \tan (A)$$

anybody knows how to get the answer? I keep getting stuck at $\frac{2\sin(A)\sin(B)}{2\cos(A)\cos(B)}$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {\cos(a-b) - \cos (a+b)}{\sin(a-b) - \sin(a+b)}\\
\frac {\cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b - \cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b}{\sin a \cos b - \cos a\sin b - \sin a\cos b - \cos a\sin b}\\
\frac {2\sin a\sin b}{-2\cos a\sin b}\\
-\frac {\sin a}{\cos a}\\
-\tan a$

Note that you have the incorrect sign from the original proposition, suggesting something was transposed in the post.

i.e. the identity was supposed to be.

$\frac {\cos(a-b) - \cos (a+b)}{\sin(a+b) - \sin(a-b)}$

And in your work, it appears that you have applied the incorrect addition identity for $\sin (a+b), \sin(a-b)$